# Could not find server 'server name' in sys.servers - sql server 2017 v14.0.3436.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We're having trouble with running SQL 'exec' but if we run 'select' we don't have a problem.

1. We had Win 2012 Servers with SQL Server 2014 -
2. We are upgrading WinOS and SQL version, so now have identical servers with Win2019 + SQL 2017 Server v14.0.3436.1
3. We restored the databases from the old servers to the new servers

We have a linked server setup, and we can run the following 'select' command against the remote server and it works fine and returns results.

i.e.:

```
select * from CSDB23.systemlive.dbo.dt_currency
```

[image]

However when we run the 'exec' command:

```
exec csdb23.systemlive.dbo.p_transfer 3,'SystemProd1'
```

we get the following issue:

```
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure systemlive.dbo.p_transfer, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 0]
Could not find server 'CSDb23' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified."
```

[image]

We see support issues suggested we drop and add the server using commands from SQL Server 2016 (but the commands given are depreciated from SQL 2016 so not relevant in 2017

```
sp_dropserver 'Server_A'
GO
sp_addserver  'Server',local
GO
```

but the linkserver is already setup:

[[image]

A bit lost on how or what I need to check so we don't get this issue?

Thank you

Comment: "but the commands given are depreciated from SQL 2016"; what commands are deprecated? `sp_dropserver` is definitly not depricated (though you need to use the droplogins parameter for remote servers), and `sp_addserver` only for remote servers, in which case you can use `sp_addlinkedserver`. It is not clear if you *did* or *didn't* drop and re-added the linked server.

Comment: thanks @HoneyBadger - The DBA on my end (I am IT Infrastructure Azure background and butting heads with the DBA)  

He said: "sp_addserver was deprecated on SQL Server 2012 and I don't believe that it's applicable to SQL Server 2017. And that the link has been removed and recreated already".

I am going to suggest we try **sp_droppserver** and then **sp_addlinkedserver** - I am just waiting for the USA to comeonline (where the DBA is from)

Comment: Can this all somehow related to case sensitivity? You have got 'CSDB23' in successful query, but 'CSDb23' in error message. Or have you some access rights issues?

Comment: Hey @Arvo - Thought this too with case sensative but tried variations without success.  It may well be related to access rights. I have added to the list of things to check. Will check in about 1 hour when DBA comes online.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue to be with the Server Name.

When the server was created in Azure, it was created with a Market Place image with SQL already a part of the image.

The server was named (just an example) "Sever-DB10". Once the servers were deployed, the name of the sever was changed to "MainDB10" - However, the SQL instance was still seeing the server as "Server-DB10" when we looked up the names of the SQL instances using:

```
select name from sys.syservers
```

We see the server was referencing the old name of the server and not the new name. We manually dropped the name and readded it back via the linked server with the correct name. - we no longer then had the main issue "Cannot find server X)

(We hada raft of other Access issues after this and eventually reinstalled SQL which seemed to completely resolve all issues we had.)